# VMWare Clarity Design System and Angular 9 Ivy strict template type checking

Tags: angular, vmware, ivy, clarity

My project uses **Angular** (v9) and **Clarity Design System** (v3).

With Ivy and the strict type checking of templates, **how do you handle the clrLayout of clrForm elements?**

```
<form clrForm clrLayout="horizontal" clrLabelSize="4">
  [...]
</form>
```

This form gives me the following error messages:

- `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.` for the attribute `clrLabelSize="4"`.
- `Type '"horizontal"' is not assignable to type 'Layouts'.` for `clrLayout="horizontal"`.

Thank you!

> Ref: https://clarity.design/documentation/forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a Clarity user, but checking the source you need to use the `Layout` enum. A string cannot be used as the enum member. To pass in a number for label size, just wrap the `[clrLabelSize]` attribute so the expression evaluates to number. Otherwise it is passed as a string.

```
import { Layouts } from '[pathToClarity]/layout.service';

export class YourComponent {
   Layouts = Layouts
}

<form clrForm [clrLayout]="Layouts.HORIZONTAL" [clrLabelSize]="4">
```

*My source were theses source files:*
[layout.service.ts](https://github.com/vmware/clarity/blob/a0aeea95360d6df07bb47156878e0ec72fbdbd4a/src/clr-angular/forms/common/providers/layout.service.ts), [layout.ts](https://github.com/vmware/clarity/blob/a0aeea95360d6df07bb47156878e0ec72fbdbd4a/src/clr-angular/forms/common/layout.ts)

Comment: For `Layouts`, it's more tricky. `@clr/angular` does not export `Layouts` and importing with a direct path to `[pathToClarity]/layout.service` does not work because `node_modules` are excluded in Angular's `tsconfig.json`. Clarity Project Team acknowledged this issue, [#3380](https://github.com/vmware/clarity/issues/3380) in GitHub. It might have been already fixed by the time you read this solution.

Comment: **workaround**: redefine `enum Layouts` inside your shared `UiModule` so that you can import it inside your components.

Comment: Wow @Thierry, thanks for investigating this. I was also afraid that the enums would not be exported.